# How do I call a function to start Qthreading?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to make a program that can pixelate images. When the image is uploaded, the image is suppose to go through the color_quantization function then the pixelate function. But when I run the program, the image only goes through the pixelate function.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as Qtw, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from pixel import Ui_Form
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
import cv2
import numpy as np


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    hash = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def color_quantization(self, img, k=3):
        data = np.float32(img).reshape((-1, 3))
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 20, 0.001)
        ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(data, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
        center = np.uint8(center)
        result = center[label.flatten()]
        result = result.reshpe(img.shape)
        for x in result:
            self.hash.emit(x)
            return x


class Pixel(Qtw.QWidget):
    hash_requested = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.upload.clicked.connect(self.upload_image)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.hash.connect(self.upload_image)
        self.hash_requested.connect(self.worker.color_quantization)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def upload_image(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter="Image(*.*)")[0]
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        self.pixelate(img)

    def pixelate(self, image):
        height, width = image.shape[:2]
        w, h = (128, 128)
        temp = cv2.resize(image, (w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        output = cv2.resize(temp, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.ui.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qtw.QApplication([])
    win = Pixel()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: It seems that the only way to execute `color_quantization` is when `hash_requested` is emitted, but that signal is never emitted at all.

Comment: `worker.hash` should be connected to `pixelate`, and the line `self.pixate(img)` should be replaced with `self.hash_requested.emit(img)`. The `color_quantization` function looks totally broken, though. What is the purpose of the for-loop, and the return statement? Why aren't you emitting an image? What is `reshpe`? I suggest you properly test that function before trying to get the threading to work.